# Laravel 5.4 relationships with all()

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationships

I have two tables, **QA** and **QACategories**.

QA has the usual fields (increment etc) and also a field **category_id**.

QA categories has the usual plus a field "category".

The model for QA is:

```
class QandA extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'qa';

     public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('QACategories::class');
    }
}
```

and the QACategories is

```
class QACategories extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'qacategories';

    public function question()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('QandA::class');
    }
}
```

All I want to do is return them all from a controller and pass them to a view with the category. If I do

```
class QandAController extends Controller
{


    public function Datatable()
        {
            $questions = QandA::all();
            dd($questions);
            return view('datatables.qa',['questions'=>$questions]);
        }
}
```

(I have referenced the QA class. If I use the code above the dd is fine, but when I try to add ->category in anyway I am told

```
Property [category] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Help, please! I know it is something very stupid.

Comment: When you use ::class, don't put it in parentheses. So: `$this->hasOne(QACategories::class);` instead of `$this->hasOne('QACategories::class')`

Comment: I have done this but I am still getting

Property [category] does not exist on this collection instance.

$questions = QandA::all()->category;
 dd($questions);

Comment: try this  return view('datatables.qa') ->with('questions', $questions);

Comment: Getting the view is not the problem but the dd does not show the category relationshp

Comment: You can specify the column to match as a second / third argument, I guess the QACategories will default to a column of qua_category_id OR q_a_category_id instead of the assumed category_id (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)